# How to allow the root user to write files into HDFS

Tags: linux, hadoop

I have installed hadoop on Cent OS 7. The daemon service written in python trying to  make a directory in HDFS , but getting the below permission error.

```
mkdir: Permission denied: user=root, access=WRITE, inode="/rep_data/store/data/":hadoop:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x
```

looks like my service is running under root account.
So I would like to know how do I give a permission to the root user to make directory and write files.

Comment: Please note that Stackoverflow is for programming related questions only. Please review the [help/on-topic] for what topics can be asked here. This question may be appropriate on other SE sites such as [unix.se] or [Superuser](http://superuser.com). Check their help first to see if the question belongs there and if so you can click the "flag" link and select "in need of moderator attention" to request migration there.

Comment: I think it is related to programming, the service which I referred here is written by me in python. So the python code is trying to make directory in hadoop.

Comment: It doesn't matter that the question arose from a programming activity. The point is that the question itself is not directly related to programming (someone not doing programming could have exactly the same question). You are asking about setting permissions which is a sysadmin question not a programming one. If you are asking how to set the permissions in the code itself then that would make it a programming question.  But the question is not worded like that and sounds like you just want to set up your system correctly.

Comment: Are you familiar with `chmod`? You directory clearly does not allow write access to any user but the `hadoop` user

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create directory under HDFS root i.e `/`, you may face this type of issue. You can create directories in your home, without any issues

To create directory in root, Execute command like follows

`sudo hdfs hdfs dfs -mkdir /directory/name`

To create directory in your HDFS home execute below command

`hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/user_home/directory/name`

Comment: Through the command line , I am able to make the directory in hadoop. But I am getting the error when the python program is trying to make the directory.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an issue because you are not the [super user](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsPermissionsGuide.html#The_Super-User).

A workaround is to enable Access Control Lists in hdfs and give permissions to your user.
 To enable support for ACLs, set `dfs.namenode.acls.enabled` to true in the NameNode configuration.

For more info check: [link](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsPermissionsGuide.html#ACLs_Access_Control_Lists)

Comment: For time being I changed the owner of the folder /rep_data/store/data/ from hadoop to root using chown which resolved the issue.

Comment: You can add your user(hadoop) to sudoer group and use `sudo <command>` from the next time.